# how to Hide Main Form in C#

Tags: c#

Hi Developers And Programmers

I want to hide the main form without child form

Code

```
public partial class frmKey : Form
{
    public frmKey()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Hide();
    }
}
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: Think about what happens when call this code: _frmKey f = new frmKey();
f.Show();_ The Hide is called in the constructor, but then you call Show() so...

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to hide it in the OnLoad event.